# Blender: Impossible Cube

Tags: c++, graphics, transparency, blender, raytracing

I'm working on a graphics project trying to create an impossible cube in 3D. An impossible cube looks like that:

[image]

The trick behind this is two of the edges which are 'cut' and a picture taken from a specific angle to give the illusion of the impossibility. 
[image]

Well I'm trying to make this but instead of a static image, I want to be able to animate it (rotate around) maintaining the impossible properties.

I have managed to make a cube in blender as you can see in the screenshot below:
[image]

I would like to hear your suggestions as to how I can achieve the desired effect. An idea would be to make transparent the portion of the edge that has an edge(or more) behind it, so that every time the camera angle changes, the transparent patch moves along.

It doesn't have to be done in Blender exclusively so any solutions in OpenGL etc are welcome.

To give you an idea of what the end result should be, this is a link to such an illustration:

[3D Impossible Cube Illusion Animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUByid1Qfzo)

Comment: Not sure about Blender, but in OpenGL, you might try playing with different arguments to glDepthFunc to try to get the effect that you're looking for.

Comment: Seems a legitimate question. Not sure why it was down-voted initially.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. The vote appear not even a minute after I uploaded the question so somebody's messing around..

Comment: The only thing that I can say is that you probably do not want to do it in Blender (at least not using the Python API). Blender's editor works in such a way that is needs to change the state of the file (for example move vertex coordinates, or change transparency) and only then displays it, so you'd have to write some very complicated code that does this while you move the camera. 
Alternatively, also if you want to do it in the Blender Game Engine, it would not be fun, I reckon.

That leaves us with the option of OpenGL, but I can't think of a solution right away.

Comment: I will keep this thread open and please share it to people that could be of any assistance, thanks

Comment: You need to further nail down the algorithm by which this illusion would work. Right now, you have exactly one case: viewing it from a certain angle. If you want to rotate it, then you need an algorithm that works for all cases. And there's no way to know what that is unless you know *exactly* what effect you want. For example, I could suggest something that would give a *similar* appearance, but it wouldn't be exactly like the original.

Comment: @BenVoigt Looks great but this is exactly what I don't want to do. this is creating a static image while I need to maintain the effect while rotating the figure ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible (heh). Try to imagine rotating the cube so that the impossibly-in-front bit moves to the left. As soon as it would "cross" the current leftmost edge, the two properties of "it's in front" and "it's in the back" will not be possible to fulfill simultaneously.

Comment: read the description and watch youtube...

Comment: Look. Either the yellow top-side would end up in front of the blue front-side in the back, as it should by regular-cube geometry, or it will end up occluded by the blue front-side, as it should by impossible-cube geometry. No matter what you do, one of those rules will end up broken. It only works in the impossible-cube perspective because those two don't overlap.

Comment: @AlexEncoreTr: "*watch youtube*" What Youtube? You didn't link to a video.

Comment: Note how, with that animation, they cleverly avoid crossing the two edges I indicated. You cannot freely rotate such a cube without discontinuities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have edge culling enabled, but clipping (depth-testing) disabled, and draw primitives in the right order, you should get the Escher cube without any need for cuts.  This should be relatively easy to animate.